# Reducing Cognitive Complexity of Six-Way Cartesian Product

Tags: java

I have a piece of code that has [Cognitive Complexity](https://blog.sonarsource.com/cognitive-complexity-because-testability-understandability) of 21

```
for (String item1 : itemList1){
    for (String item2 : itemList2){
        for (String item3 : itemList3){
            for (String item4 : itemList4){
               for (String item5 : itemList5){
                   for (String item6 : itemList6){
                       methodToRun(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6);
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Our linter specifies a maximum Cognitive Complexity of 15, so I should reduce this by the standards we've been following.

Can anyone suggest an alternative solution to this piece of code? Or is leaving it like this acceptable despite the complexity being too high?

I know this could be a personal opinion, but I'm looking for genuine solutions or answers from people who have had similar situations before.

EDIT : I cannot access a lot of libraries and packages from the dev machine I'm working on. I have access to some (too many to list), so please take note of this before suggesting use of one.

Comment: How is `itemList2` related to `itemList1`? Are they entirely separate?

Comment: What is this "Cognitive Complexity" measure? I can't reduce it without knowing how it works.

Comment: @adarshr Each `List` contains a set of data that needs to be iterated through and compared with each other piece of data from each list.

Comment: @marstran I've added a link in the question to an article on cognitive complexity that should explain it

Comment: I wouldn't change the code just for the sake of getting rid of the message. Instead you should tackle the reason behind the design, why do you even need this? Maybe you can change the design behind such that you won't need such nested loops in the first place.

Comment: @Zabuza I'm in the position that I don't think the code should change. However I'm supposed to be following the standards set out in the linter. I can likely present an argument that enables me to keep the code as it is. But what I'm looking for is alternatives that would lower the complexity, or experiences from others that show it isn't needed to change the code. 
I need to iterate through each item in each list for each other item in each other list, so the design of the code is needed in order to iterate through each item.

Comment: As shown by @dasblinkenlight, you can probably *cheat* your way around the message. But that doesn't solve the real problem, the reason why the style-checker shows this message in the first place. However, there are some cases where one should ignore a style-checker message, therefore most support some kind of **suppress command**. In most cases, however, you can change the design and get rid of the problem by that.

Comment: @Zabuza I'm happy to suppress the message, I was just looking to get some ideas on what other developers would do in the same situation. I quite like the answers you've presented in the comments, so if you want to add them as an official answer I'll accept it. From what you and others are saying I think the sensible option is just to suppress the message as I'm happy with the code as it stands myself.

Comment: I was previously unfamiliar with Cognitive Complexity but it is fair to say that we all strive for intuitive code.  The code above is not easily comprehended until you internalize that a cartesian product is being constructed, and processing must be done on the full union of lists.  Had the code been "processCartesianProduct(list1, list2,..) it would have been more intuitive. At this point you have two options: 1) Write this method as above, and suppress the warning because you 'understand' it, 2) write a more intuitive cartesian product.  I prefer the latter (unless this is a unique use case)

Answer (score 3):

You can go for a recursive solution. It is arguably less readable, but has a much smaller level of nesting, which reduces the complexity measure:

```
static void recursiveRun(List<List<String>> list, int pos, String[] item) {
    if (pos == 6) {
          methodToRun(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4], item[5]);
    } else {
        for (String s : list.get(pos)) {
            item[pos] = s;
            recursiveRun(list, pos+1, item);
        }
    }
}
```

The initial call looks like this:

```
recursiveRun(
    Arrays.asList(itemList1, itemList2, itemList3, itemList4, itemList5, itemList6)
,   0
,   new String[6]
);
```

Comment: Gets rid of the message but, as you said, it doesn't tackle the problem behind. Basically it has the same problem than the code of OP, just that the message probably won't trigger.

Comment: @Zabuza I don't think there's any "problem behind." It does not look like OP has a problem with the algorithm for his solution, only with its implementation. There is nothing wrong with six nested loops when what you need is a Cartesian product of six different lists. If the tool allows for exceptions from rules, this would probably be the place where such an exception would be entirely warranted.

Comment: It's surprising that the Cognitive Complexity measure penalizes deep nesting but not recursion?

Comment: @karakfa ok I have to withdraw my previous statement - at least the sonarQube-metric for Cognitive Complexity *does* penalize recursion: https://www.sonarsource.com/docs/CognitiveComplexity.pdf

Answer (score 2):

### Google Guava solution

Once your data is packed in `List<List<String>>` then you can use **n-ary Cartesian Product** preserving the order of elements (lexicographical) implemented in Google Guava.

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

List<List<String>> input = Arrays.asList(
    ImmutableList.of("Mary", "Alice"),
    ImmutableList.of("Smith", "Darcy", "Brown"),
    ImmutableList.of("Ford", "Saab")
);

List<List<String>> result = Lists.cartesianProduct(input); //Cognitive Complexity of 0

for (List<String> shuffle: result) {
    System.out.println(String.join(",", shuffle));
}
```

... produces:

```
Mary,Smith,Ford
Mary,Smith,Saab
Mary,Darcy,Ford
Mary,Darcy,Saab
Mary,Brown,Ford
Mary,Brown,Saab
Alice,Smith,Ford
Alice,Smith,Saab
Alice,Darcy,Ford
Alice,Darcy,Saab
Alice,Brown,Ford
Alice,Brown,Saab
```

---

### Pure Java half-solution

Here is a quick solution with hard-coded values for 3 lists which potentially could get generalized without incurring too much of complexity penalty.It basically does some neat (a.k.a **hard to follow**) index calculations.

```
String[] list0 = new String[] {"0", "1"};
String[] list1 = new String[] {"4", "5"};
String[] list2 = new String[] {"8", "9"};

int[] indexes = new int[3];

long totalPermutations = list0.length * list1.length * list2.length;

for(int i = 0; i < totalPermutations; i++) {
    indexes[0] = i % list0.length;
    indexes[1] = (i / list0.length) % list1.length;
    indexes[2] = (i / (list0.length * list1.length)) % list2.length;
    System.out.println(list0[indexes[0]] + "," + list1[indexes[1]] + "," + list2[indexes[2]]);

}
```

---

### Metrics discussion

Pure Java solution is a perfect example where for the sake of keeping the metric happy, we had actually increased the complexity and maintainability.

That whole index calculation is tbh quite horrible and took few goes to get right. It will most likely cost a penalty in general solution anyway as iteration will be required. Other solutions I have found on the web (including recursive and functional) are not clearer than the bunch of nested loops.

**Invented here** Cartesian product routines will IMO be more complex (even if scoring lower complexity) to comprehend.

Software has to build on abstractions, and using open, well designed 3rd party dependency makes the whole issue go away nicely.

Comment: Sadly I can't use these packages, otherwise I would like this solution.

Comment: You'll find other such "cartesian product" implementations. Once I wrote one at https://github.com/javagl/Combinatorics/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/utils/math/combinatorics/MixedRangeCombinationIterable.java , consider it as "public domain".

Comment: One downside of the approach is the unnecessary intermediate structure of the order or M^N for M lists of N elements.  For 6 lists each 10 elements, it will be 1,000,000.

Comment: thanks @Marco13 ! that's a nice solution. It would vert likely cost a lot of cognitive complexity points. I suppose some things have inherent base line complexity (especially when done as universal).

Comment: @karakfa would you say that iterative approach is most space efficient?

Comment: @diginoise Yes, of course.  iteration doesn't need to construct new objects.  With lazy languages (i.e. Haskell) your first solution is the best approach since nothing will be pre-generated until consumption.  Here as well the simplest both in terms of CC metric and with real humans.  But only suitable for small lists.

Comment: @JoshGordon I have added 'Pure Java' solution, but I argue against it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an iterator based solution.

```
class CartesianProductIterator<T> implements Iterator<List<T>>, Iterable<List<T>> {
    private List<List<T>> data;
    private int size;
    private int[] sizes;
    private int[] cursors;
    private boolean done;

    public CartesianProductIterator(List<List<T>> data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.size = data.size();
        this.sizes = new int[this.size];
        this.cursors = new int[this.size];
        setSizes(data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {return !done;}

    @Override
    public List<T> next() {
        if (! hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        ArrayList<T> tuple = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {tuple.add(data.get(i).get(cursors[i]));}
        updateCursors();
        return tuple;
    }

    private void updateCursors() {
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (cursors[i] < sizes[i] - 1) {
                cursors[i]++;
                break;
            } else {
                cursors[i] = 0;
                if (i == 0) done = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void setSizes(List<List<T>> data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {sizes[i] = data.get(i).size();}
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove is not supported here");
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {return this;}
}
```

can be used to create cross products on demand

```
List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
data.add(Arrays.asList("1", "2"));
data.add(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));

Iterator<List<String>> dataIterator = new CartesianProductIterator<String>(data);
while (dataIterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(dataIterator.next());
}
```

now with dual Iterable/Iterator interface can alternatively used as

```
for(List<String>  combination: new CartesianProductIterator<>(data)) {
        System.out.println(combination);
}
```

Comment: Except for some details (e.g. throwing `NoSuchElementException` in `next` if `!hasNext` etc), I'd vote for this one. It can nicely be encapsulated and wrapped into an `Iterable` for using it in a forach-loop, and does not need to construct the results in memory.

Comment: fixed, `next()`. Also converted to dual Iterator/Iterable interface for forEach loops.

Comment: Is it just me, or does it seem like we've utterly lost the plot if we think the above is a more understandable solution than the seven lines of code in the question? I'm not saying this answer is bad code by any means, but it does look like a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: Well... Java is verbose. Good news is it's generic enough to be reused.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to follow up on my comment with some workable code.  I then realized that the recursive parts are very much like @dasblinkenlight (I assure you that is not intended), so I hesitate posting this (just refer to his).  However this is a little more generic.  I am upvoting @dasblinkenlight.

```
public class CartesianProduct {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
    List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("d", "e", "f"));
    List<String> l3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("g", "h"));

    processCartesianProduct(new MyCartesianProductTask(), l1, l2, l3);
}

private static void processCartesianProduct(CartesianProductTask task, List<String>... lists) {
    processCP(task, new String[lists.length], 0, lists);

}

private static void processCP(CartesianProductTask task, String[] element, int pos, List<String>... lists) {
    if (pos == lists.length)
        task.doTask(element);
    else {
        for (String s : lists[pos]) {
            element[pos] = s;
            processCP(task, element, pos+1, lists);
        }
    }
}


interface CartesianProductTask {
    public void doTask(String[] element);
}

static class MyCartesianProductTask implements CartesianProductTask {

    @Override
    public void doTask(String[] element) {
        System.out.println("Performing task on: "+Arrays.asList(element));
        // Business logic goes here
    }

}

}
```

Produces:

```
Performing task on: [a, d, g]
Performing task on: [a, d, h]
Performing task on: [a, e, g]
Performing task on: [a, e, h]
Performing task on: [a, f, g]
Performing task on: [a, f, h]
Performing task on: [b, d, g]
Performing task on: [b, d, h]
Performing task on: [b, e, g]
Performing task on: [b, e, h]
Performing task on: [b, f, g]
Performing task on: [b, f, h]
Performing task on: [c, d, g]
Performing task on: [c, d, h]
Performing task on: [c, e, g]
Performing task on: [c, e, h]
Performing task on: [c, f, g]
Performing task on: [c, f, h]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on computing an index in a Cartesian Product:

- Compute the size of each sub-space by multiplying the size of the next sub-space by the size of the current vector; size of a "point space" is 1.
- Iterate over all indexes in the space. Index in space `i` can be computed by dividing by the size of sub-space and MOD-ing the result with the size of the vector.

Here is an implementation:

```
static void iterateCartesian(List<List<String>> lists) {
    int[] size = new int[lists.size()+1];
    size[lists.size()] = 1;
    for (int i = lists.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        size[i] = size[i+1]*lists.get(i).size();
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i != size[0] ; i++) {
        methodToRun(
            lists.get(0).get((i/size[1]) % lists.get(0).size())
        ,   lists.get(1).get((i/size[2]) % lists.get(1).size())
        ,   lists.get(2).get((i/size[3]) % lists.get(2).size())
        ,   lists.get(3).get((i/size[4]) % lists.get(3).size())
        ,   lists.get(4).get((i/size[5]) % lists.get(4).size())
        ,   lists.get(5).get((i/size[6]) % lists.get(5).size())
        );
    }
}
```

This solution is pretty "flat," but it requires a fair amount of quantitative abilities to understand.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/ODdnC7)

Answer (score -1):

I don't advocate this approach, but I think it (a) would suppress the warning and (b) might give you a way to think about how to break out the code to help it make more sense.  I don't find this clearer or more readable than the original, but depending on what all the terms mean in your context, it might suggest useful new directions.

```
void a(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6) {
  for (String s1: list1) {
    b(s1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6)
  }
}

void b(s1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6) {
  for (String s2: list2) {
    c(s1, s2, list3, list4, list5, list6)
  }
}

void c(s1, s2, list3, list4, list5, list6) {
  for (String s3: list3) {
    d(s1, s2, s3, list4, list5, list6)
  }
}

void d(s1, s2, s3, list4, list5, list6) {
  for (String s4: list4) {
    e(s1, s2, s3, s4, list5, list6)
  }
}

void e(s1, s2, s3, s4, list5, list6) {
  for (String s5: list5) {
    f(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, list6)
  }
}

void f(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, list6) {
  for (String s6: list6) {
    methodToRun(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6)
  }
}
```

Comment: This gets rid of the problem yes, but gives an overall much worse and less readable piece of code. I don't care if I have to suppress the warning, I'm just looking for a more elegant solution if one exists.